# AngularJS and Electron: Can't run AngularJS application inside Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, html, electron

I create simple game using HTML 5, CSS 3, EcmaScript 6, AngularJS 1.7.7, and JQuery 3.3.1. The game run smoothly when tested using Firefox, but when I ported it into desktop application using Electron the game goes wrong. It show errors in electron debugger like I screenshot below.

[Errors in Electron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDBeU.png)

```
Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.7/jqLite/nosel
    at angular.min.js:7
    at Object.Y [as element] (angular.min.js:33)
    at functions.js:5 angular.min.js:127
Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.7/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=gameController
    at angular.min.js:7
    at angular.min.js:97
    at ea (angular.min.js:79)
    at p (angular.min.js:71)
    at g (angular.min.js:64)
    at angular.min.js:64
    at angular.min.js:22
    at m.$eval (angular.min.js:154)
    at m.$apply (angular.min.js:154)
    at angular.min.js:22
```

[image]

The game when run in browser run smoothly like I screenshot below.

[Browser Version of Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87nUU.png)

[image]

Because Electron based on Chromium and node.js, I tested it on Chrome too. When I tested using Chrome the game run smoothly. I can't find out what's wrong with the code. I search in google just to found out question and answer about Angular CLI, TypeScript, and Electron, but I am using native Javascript, JQuery, AngularJS, and Electron so their question and answer is useless for me.

I post web version of my game in [GitHub](https://github.com/colorful-hornbill-studio/borneo-space-war/), for javascript file you can look at this [link](https://github.com/colorful-hornbill-studio/borneo-space-war/blob/master/js/functions.js). Desktop version of game is nearly same with web version, the only differences is new file of main.js and package.json. For script in main.js and package.json, you can look at end of this question (all other resources like images, sounds, and etc have loaded correctly, the problem I found is AngularJS and functions.js file).

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        fullscreen: true
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html')

    win.webContents.openDevTools()

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if(win ===  null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "borneo-space-war",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Simple space shooting game with unique concept.",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "electron ."
    },
    "author": "Atallabela Yosua",
    "license": "GNU General Public License v3.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^4.1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: When you post images of error messages, it makes it difficult to copy their text for the purpose of seaching. For information on the `jqLite:nosel` error, see [AngularJS Error Reference - jqLIte: nosel](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/jqLite/nosel). *In order to resolve this error ... you can include a full version of jQuery, which AngularJS will automatically use and that will make all selectors available.*

Comment: Thanks, but I am using JQuery from very beginning and it have loaded too, so what do yo mean by **full version of JQuery**. Does it mean I'cant use *angular.element('element-selector')* inside electron. How about change it to *$('element-selector')* or *document.querySelector('element-selector')*, is it able to resolve errors?

Comment: You will get better error messages if you use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`. For more information on jqLite, see [AngularJS API Reference - jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite).

Comment: For more information on the other error, see https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.7/docs/error/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=gameController